# python: Create new lists by summing values of multiple lists

Tags: python

I want to create a new list that is the sum of the columns of the previous lists.

I have a lot of different lists and I would like to sum up all of the different lists in the most efficient way possible. Below is an example of the issue I am trying to solve:

```
list[0] = [2,4,1,6,7] 
list[1] = [3,1,2,11,0]
list[2] = [2,4,2,2,1]
...
list[999] = [4,2,5,6,7]
```

The newlist would then look something like this:

> Newlist = [1340,1525,675,1825,895]

What would be the best way to create the new list.

Comment: you mean sum up all the elements in all the lists?

Comment: yes sum up all values in the lists and create a new list with 5 new (summed) values.

Comment: Could you include a [mcve] that makes sense with the numbers. It seems like you want `2 + 3 + 2 + ... + 4` to return `1340` but without having the actual numbers that is just an educated guess. For example you could omit the sublists from index 4 onwards and adapt the numbers accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think of this solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = list()

a.append([2, 4, 1, 6, 7])   # a[0]
a.append([3, 1, 2, 11, 0])  # a[1]
a.append([2, 4, 2, 2, 1])   # a[2]

# 1st solution

rslt_1 = a[0]

for _ in range(1, len(a)):
    rslt_1 = np.add(rslt_1, a[_])

# 2nd solution

rslt_2 = np.sum(a, axis=0)

print("Rslt_1:", rslt_1)
print("Rslt_2:", rslt_2)
```

Returns:

```
Rslt_1: [ 7  9  5 19  8]
Rslt_2: [ 7  9  5 19  8]
```